# How are these two Breadth First Search problems different from each other

Tags: algorithm, matrix, breadth-first-search

Below are two breadth first search traversal problems.

***Problem 1 : 317 - Shortest Distance From All Buildings***
[image]

The solution for this problem is to do a breadth first search traversal from each building, and record the distance to the reachable cells from it.
The shortest distance would be the cell that is reachable from each of the buildings, and have the cumulative shortest distance over distance to reach that cell from each building.

***Problem 2 : 296 - Best Meeting Point***
[image]
I find this problem to be exactly the same as previous, except that there are no 2, that is, obstacles here. Why is there a different solution however?

I am trying to understand the difference between the two problems, and why the solution of the first problem won't work for the second. Does Manhattan distance have anything to do with it?

EDIT : Based on SimMac's answer below, I have tried to update the Manhattan and Travelling distance starting from the building at `(0,1)`. The input as well as Manhattan and Travelling distance are below. SimMac, could you please validate these.

```
Input
0 - 1 - 2 - 0 - 1
|   |   |   |   |
0 - 2 - 0 - 0 - 0
|   |   |   |   |
0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1


Manhattan distance
1 - source - INF - 8 -   9
|      |     |     |     |
2 -   INF -  6 -   7 -   8
|      |     |     |     |
3 -    4 -   5 -   6 -   7

Travelling Distance
1-   source- INF - INF - INF
|      |     |     |     |
2 -   INF - INF - INF - INF
|      |     |     |     |
3 -   INF - INF - INF - INF
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use first algorithm for second problem, but it isn't neccessary.

You already mentioned the Manhattan distance. Instead of doing a BFS to calculate the distance between two points, you can now simply calculate the Manhattan distance and use this value. Because the manhattan distance between two points (x1, y1), (x2, y2) is simply the absolute difference of x1 and x2 plus the absolute difference of y1 and y2, it is much faster to calculate the distance this way.

You can't use the Manhattan distance on the first problem, because you may have a situation like this:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 0 - 1
|   |   |   |   |
0 - 2 - 0 - 0 - 0
|   |   |   |   |
0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1
```

You can easily see how the traveling distance from the building at `(0,1)` to any point not in the rightmost column differs from the Manhattan distance.

Let's draw the traveling distances from the building to every other field:

```
1 - x - + - 8 - 9
|   |   |   |   |
2 - + - 6 - 7 - 8
|   |   |   |   |
3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
```

The Manhattan distance would look like this (it isn't affected by the obstacles):

```
1 - x - + - 2 - 3
|   |   |   |   |
2 - + - 2 - 3 - 4
|   |   |   |   |
3 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But makes me wonder - Since the first problem does not allow moving diagonally, isn't BFS distance same as Manhattan distance? Please confirm. Assuming that is correct, my question would be, why not use the algorithm from the second problem, which you rightly call "faster" to solve the first as well? Is it because, the first one has obstacles (2) that you cannot pass through and so Manhattan would fail? I think, I'm still trying to understand how the two problems are different from each other, and why we wouldn't be able to use the faster/simpler method to solve both.

Comment: @PepperBoy I updated my answer to address your comment (formatting is easier in the answer than in the comments). I hope this answers your question?

Comment: thanks again, spent some time on it, but haven't got it yet. Firstly, I don't see a building at (1,0) in the input you provided. In the description, building are marked by 1, whereas, (1,0) in the input is 0, which is an empty land. Second, I have tried to update the Manhattan and Traveling distance as an edit to the original question, but wouldn't bet on these being right. Would you mind giving me an example or two of a couple of places where the Manhattan and Traveling distances are different.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant (0, 1). Why are the traveling distances on every column but the rightmost infinite? I updated my answer once again with the traveling distance, now you can easily compare them with the Manhattan distance.

Comment: Oh, I see now, it looks like you didn't quite get the Manhattan distance. The Manhattan distance is always just the sum of the absolute vertical and absolute horizontal difference, the Manhattan difference between (0,1) and (0,3) is always 2, regardless of whether there is an obstacle or not (which makes it so fast to compute, you literally just have to calculate |p1.x - p2.x| + |p1.y - p2.y|, which is done in constant time.

Comment: makes a lot more sense now, thanks! In summary, does it make sense to say that, Problem 1 does not work with Manhattan distances due to the presence of 2s (obstacles). Apart from that, both questions are identical especially since problem 1 does not allow you to move diagonally. For the purpose of discussion, if we were to assume that Problem 1 did not have any 2s, but diagonal movement was allowed, the Manhattan distance would still not work, since the movement from say, (0,0) to (1,1) would've been a Traveling distance / BFS distance of 1, but a Manhattan distance of 2 ?